# android http URL connection working with https, not working with http

Tags: java, android, http, url, connection

I have tried to perform an http GET by using the following code. It works perfectly with https URL string, instead with http url doesn't work.

I Do not understand why. An IOException is given.
Can you help? I have tried to retrieve the same URL, for instance google, with and without, https, the latter is working. What's the issue? I have added in the manifest the users permission to access internet.

```
package com.example.httptest;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        //URL url = new URL("https://www.fineco.it");
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
        Log.e("MAU","0");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.e("MAU","1");
        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.e("MAU","2");

        if (code == 200) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            if (in != null) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;
            }
            in.close();
        }
        Log.e("MAU",result);

        return result;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("MAU","Malformed URL");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("MAU","IOException");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your androidManifest.xml in application tag & try debugging it

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find this post which solved the issue
https://medium.com/mindorks/my-network-requests-are-not-working-in-android-pie-7c7a31e33330